# Filter dictionary by int range in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
Dictionary<int,Observation>
```

and I want to create a new dictionary with keys range 1 to 10,000 for example.

What I've got is

```
Dictionary<int,Observation> source;
Dictionary<int,Observation> newDict = new Dictionary<int,Observation>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    newDict[i] = new Observation(source[i]);         
}
```

Is there any efficient way to create a new dictionary that contains only the keys suitable to a given range (of ints, ofcourse)?

I'm new to LINQ but I guess there's a way to make it.

Comment: `Is there any efficient way`, doe this imply that the code you have is not efficient?

Comment: No, the code is efficient, but I want to make it ellegant while saving its efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Where` (with any condition you want) and `ToDictionary` after

```
newDict = source.Where(x => x.Key < 10000 && x.Key > 10)
                                      .ToDictionary(x=>x.Key,x=>x.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working:
    dObservations = new Dictionary<int, Observation>(exIn.dObservations.Where(x => (x.Key <= iEnd && x.Key >= iStart)).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key,x=>x.Value));

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Take Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this:

```
var newDict = source.OrderBy(d => d.Key)
                    .Take(10000)
                    .ToDictionary(d=>d.Key,d=>d.Value);
```

Also you can use [Skip Extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/bb358985%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
var newDict = source.OrderBy(d => d.Key)
                    .Skip(1000).Take(10000)
                    .ToDictionary(d=>d.Key,d=>d.Value);
```

That will `Skip` first 1000 elements then Take 10000 records.

Or you can use Where to get specific range:

```
var newDict = source.Where(d => d.Key >= start && d.Key <= end)
                    .ToDictionary(d => d.Key,d => d.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there any way to use the 2 range ints (iStart, iEnd) in that query?

Comment: I'm not sure but check my answer, Skip maybe  help you

Comment: @Selman22 Skip and Take will return `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int,Observation>>` not dictionary :)

Comment: Note that "keys in the range 1 to 10.000" and "the first 10.000" keys are two different queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var newDict=source.Keys.Where(c=> c >= rangeMinimum && c<=rangeMaximum).ToDictionary(c=>c,c=>source[c]);
```

where rangeMinimum and rangeMaximum is the start and end of your range. In your example, 0 and 9999.